# Do the /sit macro and/or mashing the X button work for the purposes of Paladin Reckoning? How?

Tags: world-of-warcraft-classic

[Reckoning](https://classic.wowhead.com/spell=20182/reckoning) is a Paladin's ability in Classic/Vanilla World of Warcraft (1.13/1.12). When fully leveled, after being subject to a critical hit, the user gets a "reckoning stack", becoming entitled to an extra attack against the opponent when the Paladin starts auto-attacking.

On private pirated servers, abusing this mechanic was very easy: one simply needed to make a macro including a /sit command: a character gets critically hit if struck while sitting. That is why many guides written between the death of official Vanilla WoW suggest this as a strategy.

However, there are a lot of claims that this combo does not work, and was only a feature of private servers, which indeed implemented many things wrong. On real Classic/Vanilla servers, [one has to repeatedly press the X button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuPEzEoexLI) and be in standing animation while struck -- this is how it is described by most Paladin players correcting the "Reckoning stacking doesn't work" statements.

---

Now, my questions are:

1. Does either way of stacking Reckoning actually work in WoW Classic (1.13)?
2. If yes, how does one utilize it in PvP and PvE?
3. If yes, does one have to time the usage in a specific way? Does it require any training?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a lot of discussion about whether this actually existed on Vanilla (1.12). It is commonly agreed that the bug existed on private servers.

Whatever the history behind it, it seems like this bug was definitely live in Classic (1.13). Blizzard claimed that they fixed the bug shortly after the release. However, just after the fix, there were several claims (by streamers, etc.) that the bug could still be exploited.

I can't find the exact dates now, but it seems like it was (claimed to) be fixed somewhere in May 2019. A few hotfixes later, in June, it seems like it was definitely fixed. Thus, it should no longer be possible on current live servers.

Comment: Have you tested this personally?

Comment: Not recently, no. I played a Warrior, who could use the same mechanic to trigger a Fury talent. I was not able to do it again after they fixed it. But, I haven't played since last year, so I can't speak for recent months.